# Data processing using eloquent orm methods

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am very beginner to PHP and Laravel. 
I am using laravel 5 eloquent ORM. I have an array $caseIDs and want to fetch the data from db where caseID (column name) matches from one of the $caseIDs elements. Can I use where() method of eloquent ORM? or How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `whereIn` which simulates a `WHERE IN('comma','separated','values')`

`YourModel::whereIn('caseID', $caseIDs)`